# XNA large coordinates and float precision

Tags: xna-4.0, floating-point-precision

I have my model created in Autocad as .dwg file in large coordinates like (X = 528692.833, Y = -261.184, Z = 1.890). When the model is exported to .Fbx file, the distortions appear in the FBX Viewer and the same happens in XNA with converted .Xnb file.

What I can't understand is that, why the problem persists when the model transferred around the origin using World matrix in XNA framework. Dose the problem regard the float precision? since XNA api only works with float number. Or is there any problem with .Xnb file ?

What are the possible workarounds apart from moving the model around the origin in Autocad?

**Edit:**

Also I have realized that if instead of the BasicEffects a simple shader is used, then I wouldn't encounter this problem.

Below is a sample scene of the rendered model:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/15/distortion.png/

Comment: Can you post an example screenshot?

Comment: Thanks. here is the link to a screenshot.